# What are the requirement to use OpenGl inside a background thread?

Tags: android, delphi, opengl-es, firemonkey

What are the requirement to use OpenGl inside a background thread ? It's for an android/ios app made in Delphi. I need mostly to create texture in background thread and draw them on the app canvas in the main thread.

Comment: Idk how threading works on apps, but for laptops, you cannot initialise `GL Context` on any other thread but main thread. I assume this also applies to apps on IOS/Android. What I suggest you do is use your local image API (like `BufferedImage` or `ImageIO` in **java**), and decode the image into their respect pixels colours in a `ByteBuffer` array. Pass this array to the main thread and reassemble the image **or** directly use the `STBImage` library from OpenGL to load the buffer.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle: "Idk how threading works on apps, but for laptops, you cannot initialise GL Context on any other thread but main thread. "  That's not true at all. YOu can crate GL context on any thread, you can pass GL contexts around between threads, you can do whatever you want thread-wise as long as you stay inside GLs threading restrictions.

Comment: @derhass what are GLs threading restrictions ?

Comment: Each OpenGL context can be made current to at most one thread at a time. And each thread can have at most one current GL context. However, you can create contexts which share objects (buffers, textures, etc.) with each other, so a ressource loading thread can use its own context and still upload data used by another context in another thread.